# Extract results of "combvec" from a matrix and do the reverse the "combvec"

Tags: matlab, matrix

I am working on a combinatoric problem.

Given that **A** is a **m1 x n** matrix and **C** is a **m2 x n** cell array which each cell contains a row vector.

---

*Problem statement*

I would like to, but I don't know how to, construct a function **C = vecfactor(A)** such that **all(all(sortrows(A,1:n)==sortrows(B,1:n)))==1** where **B** is constructed by

```
B = [];

for J = 1 : m2
    newmat = combvec(cell2mat(C(J,1)),cell2mat(C(J,2)),cell2mat(C(J,3)), ...
                     cell2mat(C(J,4)),cell2mat(C(J,5)));
    B = [B; transpose(newmat)];
end
```

---

*Example of what I want to do*

If the input **A** is

```
A =  
0 1 3 0 1
0 1 0 0 1
0 1 0 1 1
1 0 3 0 1
0 2 0 0 1
2 0 3 0 0
0 0 0 0 1
0 0 3 0 1
2 2 0 0 1
3 0 3 0 1
0 1 0 0 2
```

then I will expect the output **C** should be look like this (the order of rows does not matter):

```
C = 
{[1,0,3] [0] [3] [0] [1];
[0] [1,0] [3,0] [0] [1];
[0,2] [2] [0] [0] [1];
[0] [1] [0] [1] [1];
[0] [1] [0] [0] [2]}
```

Why should **C** look like this? Since the vertical concatenation of

```
transpose(combvec([1,0,3],[0],[3],[0],[1]))
transpose(combvec([0],[1,0],[3,0],[0],[1]))
transpose(combvec([0,2],[2],[0],[0],[1]))
transpose(combvec([0],[1],[0],[1],[1]))
transpose(combvec([0],[1],[0],[0],[2]))
```

has the same size of **A** *AND*  identical to **A** after sorting the rows.

---

*How will I do if no programmings*

And here is another clarification of my problem in the other way round.
This is how I try to obtain **C** from **A** on hands.

1) Numerate the rows of matrix **A**.

```
A =
0 1 3 0 1 --- row 1
0 1 0 0 1 --- row 2
0 1 0 1 1 --- row 3
1 0 3 0 1 --- row 4
0 2 0 0 1 --- row 5
2 0 3 0 0 --- row 6
0 0 0 0 1 --- row 7
0 0 3 0 1 --- row 8
2 2 0 0 1 --- row 9
3 0 3 0 1 --- row 10
0 1 0 0 2 --- row 11
```

2) Find out sets of rows of **A** such that each set is a result of combvec.

```
Consider the rows 4, 6, 10:
1 0 3 0 1 --- row 4
0 0 3 0 1 --- row 6
3 0 3 0 1 --- row 10
```

This matrix is the same as the output of

```
transpose(combvec([1, 0, 3], [0], [3], [0], [1]))
```

so, one row of C is [1, 0, 3], [0], [3], [0], [1].

```
Consider the rows 1, 2, 7, 8
0 1 3 0 1 --- row 1
0 1 0 0 1 --- row 2
0 0 3 0 1 --- row 7
0 0 0 0 1 --- row 8
```

This matrix is the same as the output of

```
transpose(combvec([0], [1, 0], [3, 0], [0], [1]))
```

so, another row of C is [0], [1, 0], [3, 0], [0], [1].

Although row 5 is also in the form of 0 _ _ 0 1, there are no ways to generate rows 1, 2, 5, 7, 8 at once using combvec, so row 5 cannot be grouped with them.

Instead, row 5 can be grouped with 9:

```
0 2 0 0 1 --- row 5
2 2 0 0 1 --- row 9
```

as they form the output of

```
transpose(combvec([0, 2], [2], [0], [0], [1]))
```

so, the other row of C is [0, 2], [2], [0], [0], [1].

And row 3 cannot form a set of output of combvec with other rows.
So row 3 alone, in the form of [0], [1], [0], [1], [1], should be a row of C.

Row 11 and row 2 together form the output of

```
transpose(combvec([0],[1],[0],[0],[1, 2]))
```

**BUT, as row 2 is already included in the other set, so row 11 and row 2 cannot be grouped together.** Row 11 should be alone, in the form of [0], [1], [0], [0], [2], should be a row of C as well.

So the matrix **A**, after such a computation, will return a cell array **C**:

```
C = 
{[1,0,3] [0] [3] [0] [1]; ---correspond to row 4, 6, 10 of A
[0] [1,0] [3,0] [0] [1]; ---correspond to row 1, 2, 7, 8 of A
[0,2] [2] [0] [0] [1]; ---correspond to row 5, 9 of A
[0] [1] [0] [1] [1]; ---correspond to row 3 of A
[0] [1] [0] [0] [2]} ---correspond to row 11 of A
```

---

There may be more than one way to do the transformation. But I want to have an output with least number of rows.

The size of the input in the example above is just 11 x 5 which is fairly easy to be done without programming. But the matrices I need to transform is in fact in the size of like 10000 x 10, so it is pretty impossible to perform it without programming.

Can anybody give me some opinion on how I can do it?